# JS, TS, handle 3 consecutive ifs / ternaries

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to compare a title for 3 strings

here what I'm doing

```
var textMessage = ""
props.screen == 'dd' ? textMessage = "Next, select the dd " : null
props.screen == 'ff' ? textMessage = "Next, select the ff " : null
props.screen == 'ss' ? textMessage = "Next, select the ss " : null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let textMessage = 'Next, select the '
switch (props.sceen) {
  case 'dd':
    textMessage += 'dd'
    break
  case 'ff':
    textMessage += 'ff'
    break
  case 'ss':
    textMessage += 'ss'
    break
  default:
    textMessage = ''
}
```

or

```
messageDictionary = {
  dd: 'Next, select the dd ',
  ff: 'Next, select the ff ',
  ss: 'Next, select the ss '
}
textMessage = messageDict[props.screen] || ''
```

By using the second way, it will be easier for you to add the new screen option.